# How can I lock and return multiple rows from an Oracle function?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, plsql, sys-refcursor, oracle-cursor

I have been trying to address the issue of how Oracle processes `ROWNUM` and `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED` while trying to return several rows that aren't locked. I have tried a number of the solutions from the following: [Force Oracle to return TOP N rows with SKIP LOCKED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117254/force-oracle-to-return-top-n-rows-with-skip-locked), as well as several other examples that look very similar to the ones found on that question. I know Oracle AQ is probably the best solution to this, but we have very little control over the databases and I have met with considerable resistance to the idea.

The problem I am running into is trying to get the results back to Java using JDBC. I have tried `setFetchSize(20)`, but I run into the issue where only the top 20 rows are distributed to the clients. I usually see one processing agent getting all 20 rows or a few processors getting some rows, all of them adding up to 20. This is very much like the behavior one would see with using `ROWNUM` in conjunction with `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED`.

The most promising solution I have tried is the following function:

```sql
create type IND_ID as object
(
   ID varchar2(200)
);

create type IND_ID_TABLE as table of IND_ID;

create or replace function SELECTIDS return IND_ID_TABLE
   pipelined is

   ST_CURSOR SYS_REFCURSOR;
   ID_REC IND_ID := IND_ID(null);

begin
   open ST_CURSOR for
      select ID
        from TABLE
    /* where clause */
         for update SKIP LOCKED;   
   loop
      fetch ST_CURSOR
         into ID_REC.ID;
      exit when ST_CURSOR%rowcount > 20 or ST_CURSOR%notfound;
      pipe row(ID_REC);
   end loop;
   close ST_CURSOR;
   return;
end;
```

However, when I try invoking it like so:

```sql
select * from table(SELECTIDS)
```

I get an `ORA-14551: cannot perform a DML operation inside a query` error, which I now understand is an issue with transactions. Removing the locks causes the function to return rows.

How can I get multiple rows out of this function into JDBC while preserving the locks?

Comment: Can you use a procedure with a ref cursor out parameter? Or a function returning a ref cursor, I suppose. Then you'd be calling the proc/function directly rather than trying to use the function in a query. Not sure if it would avoid the issue but might be something to play with.

Comment: @AlexPoole Per your suggestion, I was able to figure out how to get at least one row out, changing this to a procedure and using an OUT parameter, and it does maintain the lock. I have also found a few PEBKAC errors and I may have an alternate solution working. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This not gonna work. You calling a pl/sql function as part of a select statement and try to start a transaction in that function. I think the error is pretty clear.

Comment: I understand where the error is, I didn't know how to accomplish what I was attempting to do, which is to have a client lock and retrieve the first 20 rows that aren't currently locked. However, I think I've come up with a completely different solution that does do what I need it to do. I am currently testing it.