# Does Oracle SKIP LOCKED prevent non-repeatable reads?

Tags: sql, oracle, transactions, isolation-level

A transaction executes these 2 statements with the READ COMMITTED isolation

```
SELECT * FROM CATS WHERE ID=1 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
SELECT * FROM CATS WHERE ID=1
```

The first query returns the ID 1 row. I wonder if the second query will always return values equals to the result of the first query?

**My concerns are the following**

I have read the following question and the associated articles: 
[Force Oracle to return TOP N rows with SKIP LOCKED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117254/force-oracle-to-return-top-n-rows-with-skip-locked).

If I understand correctly, Oracle first computes the result set, it opens the cursor and then for each row, skip the row if the row is already locked. Without `SKIP LOCKED` the result set is locked when the cursor is opened.

Is this correct?

If yes, given a READ COMMITTED isolation:

- A transaction `T1` executes this statement

  `SELECT * FROM CATS WHERE ID=1 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED`
- A concurrent transaction `T2` updates the same result set

  `UPDATE CATS SET CATS.AGE = 10 WHERE CATS.ID = 1`

I wonder given the below scenario if T2 can update a row before the row is locked by T1:

1. T1: Oracle computes the result set
2. T2: Oracle updates the same result set and COMMIT
3. T1: Oracle opens the cursor
4. T1: Oracle for each row, skips the row if the row is already locked

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `skip locked` successfully returns the `ID = 1` row subsequent queries will always return values equal to the result of the first query.
In the case of `select for update skip locked` Oracle doesn't compute result set first but instead checks blocks and rows while fetching. I'll try to explain it by writing pseudocode

```
start select for update skip locked
open cursor, skip_locked_SCN := next SCN;
start fetching
for block in table_data_blocks loop
  if block.SCN < skip_locked_SCN then  -- unchanged block
    for row in block.rows(where id = :id) loop  -- filter rows
      if row is locked then
        -- skip that row
      else 
        add_to_resultset(row);
      end if;
    end loop;
  else  -- block has been changed
    -- go to undo segment and get previous version
    undo_block := get_from_UNDO(block);  -- (ORA-01555: snapshot too old may be raised)
    for undo_row in undo_block.rows(where id = :id) loop
       actual_row = block.rows(where rowid = undo_row.rowid);  -- get actual version of appropriate row by rowid
       if actual_row is locked then
         -- skip that row
       else
         -- check if data in the row remains unchanged
         if actual_row.data = undo_row.data then
           add_to_resultset(actual_row);
         else
           -- data changed, skip that row
         end if; 
       end if; 
    end loop; 
  end if; 
end loop;
```