# SELECT .. FOR UPDATE gives error "cannot select FOR UPDATE from view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc."

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following FOR LOOP in an PLSQL Block . I want to use a FOR UPDATE clause to lock the respective row. But running the code gives following exception back:

ORA-02014: cannot select FOR UPDATE from view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc.

I looked it up, but honestly I do not understand the explanations, so I can not solve that for now.

```
FOR l_rec IN (SELECT * 
                    FROM (SELECT * 
                            FROM my_table 
                           WHERE status = 'NEW'
                        ORDER BY key_id)
                   WHERE ROWNUM <= i_max
                   FOR UPDATE)
    LOOP
      -- do work...

      UPDATE my_table SET status = 'FINISHED' WHERE key_id = l_rec.key_id;
```

Could anybody give a comprehensive explanation of what is going on here and knwos how to solve that issue?

EDIR: Forgot to mention, my_table is no view, it is just a normal table.

Comment: The error message says it quite clearly: If the view uses DISTINCT, GROUP BY or similar, you cannot select FOR UPDATE. The reason is that, in such a view, there is no 1:1 relation from rows in the view to rows in an underlying table; hence, the RDBMS does not know which records it must lock on the underlying table and refuses to do so.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166615/how-to-work-around-ora-02014-cannot-select-for-update-from-view-with-distinct

Comment: Please read: [Update top N row of a select](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=update-top-n-row-of-a-select)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be couple of reason for the error you are getting. First one is already shown by Oracle.

1) You cannot use `FOR UPDATE` for views with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc. So make sure if your table `my_table` is not such a view.

2) Considering your table `my_table` is not a view, then when you use it in `FOR LOOP` you trying to create a inline view, hence in that case as well Oracle refuses to Lock rows. The work around could be as below:

Here  i modifed the query so that it uses the table inplace of creating a inline view.

```
 FOR l_rec IN (   SELECT *
                  FROM my_table
                 WHERE     key_id IN (  SELECT key_id
                                          FROM my_table
                                         WHERE status = 'NEW'
                                      ORDER BY key_id)
                       AND ROWNUM <= i_max
                FOR UPDATE )
  LOOP

  <Do you work>
```

Comment: If you add another subquery inbetween the existing twos, your approach works, thanks! (1st level=FOR UPDATE, 2nd level= ROWNUM, 3rd Level = ORDER BY)